# Convert text top hex equivalent

Tags: converters, hex

Ive seen a lot of questions posted about coverting a string "37878" so it can be used as a int or hex value. I wanted to know how to convert lets say "EOF" to 454f46 which is the hex equivalent. Plz help. this is in c++

Answer (score 1):

The value 0x454f46 when broken into the byes 45, 4f and 46 are just the ASCII character codes for E, O and F represented in hex notation.

To get the ASCII value of a char in c, all you need to do is

```
char c = 'E'
int i = (int)c
```

And now i will hold the value 69 or 0x45.

A full example in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void convert(char *test)
{
   int i =0;

   while (test[i] != 0)
   {
      printf("%X",(int)test[i]);
      ++i;
   }
   printf("\n");

}

int main()
{
   char *test="EOF";
   convert(test);
}
```

Which produces:

```
$ gcc c2hex.c 
$ ./a.out 
454F46
```